# Keep consitant encoding between windows, unix and mssql 2014

Tags: sql-server, encoding, utf-8

I have a node application on a **unix** machine that reads a utf-8 js file created on a **windows** machine that looks like this:

`{
 "b_name": "שם של משהו", 
}`

and uses the info in the file to update a **mssql** table with a corresponding field, defined as:

`[b_name] [nvarchar](50)`

Somewhere along the way, the value of the b_name become gibberish and is saved as junk in the db. 
When I encode it to utf-8 in the file, i.e

`{
 "b_name": '×©× ×©× ××©××', //utf8.encode('שם של משהו')
}`
it is saved correctly at the db, but then it has to be decoded at the destination, and I have no control over that part, so they see it as "×©× ×©× ××©××"

Any idea how to make it consistence through out the process?

Comment: "Somewhere along the way," - what is that way exactly? How do you talk to MSSQL? If you build queries with strings, are they N-prefixed?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was this: 
(Correct for mssql@3.3.0)

We set the type of js String to VarChar instead of NVarChar:

```
//bad
request.input('string_parameter', sql.VarChar, value);
//Good
request.input('string_parameter', sql.NVarChar, value);
```